# Rails ajax:success callback not triggering in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

My ajax callbacks are not triggering in my production environment. However, they are trigering in development with no errors. I'll simplify things for the sake of discussion.

Let's say I have a link that uses `remote: true`:

```
<%= link_to "Add Foo", new_foo_path, remote: true, id: 'new-foo' %>
```

**foos_controller.rb**

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @foo = Foo.new
    render partial: 'form' if request.xhr?
  end
end
```

Using Chrome's console, I bind to `ajax:success`:

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", "#new-foo", function() { console.log("success!"); });
```

In development this works fine; I get the "success!" message in the Chrome console.

In production, however, it does not. The request is being made, the response is the `form` partial, but the callback does not fire.

Any ideas?

PS. The following *does not* work either.

```
$("#new-foo").bind("ajax:success", function() { console.log("success!"); })
```

There is no changes to `config/environments/production.rb`.

**EDIT**: It turns out ajax:error is being triggered when I click the link in production.

```
$(document).on("ajax:error", "#new-foo", function() { console.log("error"); });
```

My production logs don't show any errors, and the network tab in Chrome developer tools is showing a `200 OK` response with the partial as the body.

**However, the Content-Type header is `text/javascript` in production but `text/html` in development.** Why is the same code responding with `text/javascript` in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the browser was trying to execute the response body as JavaScript since the Content-Type header being sent back was `text/javascript` rather than `text/html`.

There are a number of ways to fix this. I chose to use jQuery's `$.ajax` function to set the `dataType` of *all* my ajax calls. This will ask the server to send back `text/html`.

```
$.ajaxSetup
  dataType: 'html'
```

However, there are a couple other ways to ask the server for a specific response. [See this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11021991/how-do-i-use-the-rails-remote-true-parameter-with-json/11023770#11023770) for details.

There is still a lingering question, though. Why was the same code sending back `text/html` in development but `text/javascript` in production?

Answer (score 0):

In case Google brought you here (like it did to me) because `ajax:success` is not working for you in a slightly different situation - when you're using `button_to` instead of `link_to`, this might save you some head banging.

Assuming you have this modified ERB:

```
<%= button_to "Add Foo", new_foo_path, remote: true, class: 'new-foo' %>
```

This JS won't work:

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", ".new-foo", function() { console.log("success!"); });
```

This won't work since the class `new-foo` is rendered on the `input` tag, while the `data-remote="true"` is rendered on the `form` tag. The `ajax:success` event fires on the `form` tag as a result -- not the child `input` tag, and that's why the `console.log` will never get called.

To fix this, change the `class` to `form_class` in the ERB:

```
<%= button_to "Add Foo", new_foo_path, remote: true, form_class: 'new-foo' %>
```