# Hansontable on rails load data from json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ruby-on-rails-4, handsontable

If I have a controller that return a json, How can I load the json data result into the page using jquery, also my webpage is using the remote true, so the request will be ajax, the result json is return to the page, bu t now I need to load the json array into the handsontable. I need somekind of binding of the data returned by the json call into the handsontable object.

```
class GradesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    logger.debug params
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: GradesDatatable.new(view_context)  }
      #format.js { @result = GradesDatatable.new(view_context).as_json }
    end
  end
end
```

Webpage

```
<div class="row">
<%= simple_form_for :filters, url: grades_index_path('json'), method: :get, :remote => true do |f| %>
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <%= f.input :curso, collection: Curso.all, :label_method => "nombre", :value_method => "nombre" %>
        <%= f.input :seccion, collection: Seccion.all, :label_method => "nombre", :value_method => "nombre" %>
        <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :tanda, [['M', 'Matutina'] ,['D', 'Despertina'],['N', 'Nocturna']], :first, :last, :checked => 'M' %>
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 columns">
       <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.button :submit, "Filtrar", :class => "button large" %>
       </div>   
    </div>
<% end %>


</div>

<div class="row">
    <div id="grades"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
  $(function(){

  data = []
  window.data = data.aaData
  var container = document.getElementById('grades');
  window.hot = new Handsontable(container,
    {
      data: window.data,
      ...
```

Comment: why dont you just make an ajax call for your data from within JS? your JS right now is setting data to an empty array and then trying to fetch the data from that, which is obviously undefined.

Comment: Well the idea is that the submit button call the json and in somehow the data array get set, but I am trying to figure out how to, I need the json to be set in the JS somehow.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Make an ajax call when the button gets clicked and in the callback set the reply to be the data.

Comment: That button is already doing the ajax call using the property remote : true, what I need is how to setup the json response in the data.

Comment: well you can "setup the response" in the format that handsontable uses. It should be either an array of arrays where each inner array contains the values of each column, in order. Or you can have a map where each key is the column name, and the value is an array with the values of each row in order.

Comment: Yea, I got that, but I am looking how to setup the response in a rails way; I found out this for example:                                                                                                      $("#filter_btn").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) { console.log("success!"); })

Comment: But that doesn't work, it should be executed after the submit button send the request to process the response. Like it say here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006784/rails-ajaxsuccess-callback-not-triggering-in-production